# How to GET data from outside an IFRAME GAS when a file is uploaded to Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I recently saw this Github example using a Google Apps Script to upload a file to Google Drive: [DRIVE EXAMPLE](https://github.com/CharlesPlucker/drive-multi-upload) The Google Apps Script project works great, but I need to know if there is a way that when I put an IFRAME with the GAS Web App on a webpage and any user upload a file, the webpage can know the file was uploaded correctly receiving any kind of data from the GAS to use it for anything else?

Comment: Have you tried using the browser window object or the browser window Session storage?  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)  If both the Apps Script Web App and the webpage are able to access the browsers window object then it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

### About [Apps Script WebApps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

- This is a combination of a server-side code.gs file and a client-side html file
- Communication between the parts is possible with [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) or [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- The WebApp can either be used as a webpage on its own, or be embedded within a iframe.
- For easier communication between client and server-side, I recommend you to integrate both the file-uploading functionalities and the feedback about the sucessfully uploaded file within the html file of the WebApp.

- For example, implement an [SuccessHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) that appends text to a  on successful upload
- Based on sample from the documentation:

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function onSuccess() {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = 'The file upload was successful';
      }

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .uploadToDrive(data);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @ziganotschka . I already know all this info about Google Apps Script and your answer confirm that it is not possible what I was looking to implement. Thank you again

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you whole set-up corectly, but you can implement an additonal WebApp that communicates both with the iframe and the container to pass data. Possible with Javascript side fetch / XML requests in conjunction with sending URL parameters to the WebApp.

Comment: I will try with two WebApp like you say but it is unnecessary complex just for sending a response to the webpage. Just to be more clear, this WebApp will works on a e-commerce that when the file is uploaded, automatically a product is added to the cart. For that reason I was looking to get a feedback from this WebApp and then code the rest on the page. Thank you very much for your time @ziganotschka

Comment: No worries. Obviously a WebApp is not a universal solution for everything - if in your case it is an overkill, there are certainly alternatives.

Comment: What other alternatives can be used? First to all, have in mind that the website is on a platform like Wix or Squarespace, and this make all things more problematic. Thank you

Comment: I am sorry, I am familiar with those :-(

Comment: Not problem! Still thank you for your answers!